# connect openshift wildfly (jboss8) websocket app with javaclient

Tags: java, android, websocket, openshift

I am currently trying to build a websockets application using Java on OpenShift Online that will be accessed by an Android application.
I am able to successfully test this application on my local workstation, but unable to access the restful url on OpenShift.

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket/helloName")
public class HelloName {....}
```

I am trying to access this resource on OpenShift using the following url: `ws://<myapp>.rhcloud.com:8000/websocket/helloName`

Does anyone have any suggestions on why this is not working?

Comment: Could you add the error that you are getting on the Android client?